# How to select wanted column from select query based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have select query which returns
id ,name ,description ,price

Im trying  to get id,price  alone based on condition it should display name ,description

```
@show =1   
select id ,name,if @show = 1 begin name ,description, end ,price from tbl
```

Thanks

Comment: Either use dynamic SQL or write your query N times with big IFs, repeating most of the code from the `SELECT` statement in each one.

Comment: it's unclear what are you trying to do here. for @show=1 `@show =1   
select id ,name,if @show = 1 begin name`??. Please edit your question and provide more details.

Comment: i pass show parameter as 0 or 1,if 0 only have to select id , price if i pass 1 it select all 4 column,thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
@show =1

if @show = 1 
begin 
select id, name, description, price from tbl
end
else begin
select id, price from tbl
end
```

Comment: thank you,my select query have 50 lines ,is there any way to do with if or case statement in select column like we have to add or remove column based on condition,any alternate can i get?

Answer (score 0):

You can join the columns you want and execute the query.

```
DECLARE @filter AS Integer
DECLARE @columns AS nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @sql AS nvarchar(50)

Set @filter = 1

if @filter = 0 
begin 
Set @columns = 'id, name, description, price'
end
else begin
Set @columns = 'id, name'
end

set @sql = 'select ' + @columns +  ' from tbl'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
print @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54125803/how-to-select-wanted-column-from-select-query-based-on-condition#comment95083651_54125803)

> i pass show parameter as 0 or 1,if 0 only have to select id , price if i pass 1 it select all 4 column

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc
  @Show BIT = 1 --i pass show parameter as 0 or 1 That means BIT Datatype(True/False)
AS
  IF @Show = 0
    SELECT ID, Price --if 0 only have to select id , price
    FROM Table
      ELSE
        SELECT * --if i pass 1 it select all 4 column
        FROM Table
```

Answer (score 0):

Your all answer helped me a lot,thanks.
finally i went this method works on string concat
fields are id,name,description,price

declare @id int;
declare @sqlcommand  nvarchar(max) ;
declare @visible int ;
set @sqlcommand   = 'select  id ,'+case when @visible = 1 then 'name ,description' else '' end +',price from tbl 
                      where id = @id'

execute sp_executesql @sqlCommand ,N'@id int',@id=@id

if i pass visible = 1
result will be 
id name desc price

visible = 0
id price

Thanks